# wrong url to css files in spring and apache tiles

Tags: spring, apache-tiles

I'm creating REST application based on spring and apache tiles. I've added .css file and on main page it work everything. I mean when I'm on `domain.com/` but when I'll go to `domain.com/something/` the url is the same and it's wrong. I would have to add `../` at the start of .css file path

How can I create (by auto) correct file path on every subpage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute paths rather than relative paths:

```
href="/css/someFile.css"
```

rather than

```
href="css/someFile.css"
```

You must also make sure that the web app's context path is always prepended, so the path should in fact be

```
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/someFile.css"
```

or, if you use the JSTL:

```
href="<c:url value='/css/someFile.css'/>"
```

Comment: and how about urls in js files? for example for json calls?